# random.c: No such file or directory

Tags: c

I'm having problem generating random integer.
I have this function:

```c
int randomIntRange(int min, int max){
    if(min > max){
        int tmp = max;
        max = min;
        min = tmp;
    }
    return (rand() % (max - min + 1)) + min; 
}
```

I set the srand(time(NULL)) at the start of the program. The point is, sometimes, randomly, when this function is called the program crashes.
I checked with the debbuger and when it crashes the debugger prints out:

```
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00007ffff7e12988 in __random () at random.c:288
288     random.c: No such file or directory.
```

I don't really get why because most of the time the function works.

Comment: `SIGINT` is what happens when you use e.g. `Ctrl-C` to kill a program from a terminal.

Comment: Also the signal is completely unrelated to the "No such file or directory" message you get. It's because the debugger (GDB I'd guess) can't find the standard library source file where `rand` was implemented. It's a common "error" for normal development, as typically only the standard library developers would have the source files for the standard library.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ok, so the SIGINT is not related with the no such file or directory?

Comment: Then how the rand function crashes the program? Is there something i'm doing wrong in the function?

Comment: Yes the signal and the debugger "error" message are totally unrelated. And the signal is not because of the code you show. If you do *not* press `Ctrl-C` in your debugger to break the program, then there's an external source that send that signal to your program. It's not a signal that can come from a "crash".

Comment: In `(max - min + 1)` what happens when `min` is a large negative value and `max` a large positive value? You have the potential for signed overflow which is undefined or at best implementation defined.